# How to force the plot to show the x-axis values in python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have an issue making a simple plot while setting the x-axis in python.
Here is my code:

```
import import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

y  = [2586.087776040828,2285.8044466570227,1991.0556336526986,1719.7261325405243,1479.8272625661773,1272.5176077500348,1096.4367842436593,949.02201512882527,826.89866676342137,726.37921828890637,636.07392349697909,553.52559247838076,480.71257022562935,418.00424110010181,364.41801903538288,318.67575156686001,280.17668207838426,248.15399589447813,221.75070551820284,199.59983992701842,179.72014852370447,162.27141772637697,147.14507926321306,134.22828323366301,123.36572367962557,114.33589702168332,106.8825327470323,100.69181027167537,95.515144406404971,91.091036326792434]
x = range(0,30)

fig3_4 ,ax3_4 = plt.subplots()
ax3_4.semilogx(range(0,30),(loss_ave_hist))
ax3_4.set_title('Validation Performance')
# ax3_4.set_xticks(np.arange(0,30, 1.0))
ax3_4.set_xlabel('i')
ax3_4.set_ylabel('Average Loss')
fig3_4.show()
plt.show()
```

I believe my code is right! Notice the line of code I commented, it should set
the axis with the values I want, however, it throws an error. I cannot figure
out why!

Here is my plot from the my plot:

[image]

Comment: Which is "the line of code I commented"? How did you get the plot, if the code throws an error? What are you actually trying to achieve? If you want help here, provide a [mcve] of the issue and the full error traceback together with a clear problem description. Also see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way to make a semilogx plot but with xticks labelled according to their original (non-log) values.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker

y = np.array([2586.087776040828, 2285.8044466570227, 1991.0556336526986, 1719.7261325405243, 1479.8272625661773, 1272.5176077500348, 1096.4367842436593, 949.02201512882527, 826.89866676342137, 726.37921828890637, 636.07392349697909, 553.52559247838076, 480.71257022562935, 418.00424110010181, 364.41801903538288, 318.67575156686001, 280.17668207838426, 248.15399589447813, 221.75070551820284, 199.59983992701842, 179.72014852370447, 162.27141772637697, 147.14507926321306, 134.22828323366301, 123.36572367962557, 114.33589702168332, 106.8825327470323, 100.69181027167537, 95.515144406404971, 91.091036326792434])
x = np.arange(1, len(y)+1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(x, y, 'o-')
ax.set_xlim(x.min(), x.max())
ax.set_xscale('log')
formatter = mticker.ScalarFormatter()
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.FixedLocator(np.arange(0, x.max()+1, 5)))
plt.show()
```

yields
[image]
`FixedLocator(np.arange(0, x.max()+1, 5)))` places a tick mark at every 5th value in `x`.
With `ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mticker.FixedLocator(x))`, the xticklabels got a bit too crowded.

---

Note I changed `x = range(0, 30)` to `x = np.arange(1, len(y)+1)` since 
the length of `x` should match the length of `y` and since we are using a logarithmic `x`-axis, it does not make sense to start at `x=0`.

Notice also that in your original code the first `y` value (2586.08...) is missing since its associated `x` value, 0, is off-the-chart on a logarithmic scale.

Answer (score 1):

I used the following and it ran without errors.

All I changed is the typo in your first line of your imports, and replaced `loss_ave_hist` with `y` (i.e. what you called your data in your question.

```
y  = [2586.087776040828,2285.8044466570227,1991.0556336526986,1719.7261325405243,1479.8272625661773,1272.5176077500348,1096.4367842436593,949.02201512882527,826.89866676342137,726.37921828890637,636.07392349697909,553.52559247838076,480.71257022562935,418.00424110010181,364.41801903538288,318.67575156686001,280.17668207838426,248.15399589447813,221.75070551820284,199.59983992701842,179.72014852370447,162.27141772637697,147.14507926321306,134.22828323366301,123.36572367962557,114.33589702168332,106.8825327470323,100.69181027167537,95.515144406404971,91.091036326792434]   

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig3_4 ,ax3_4 = plt.subplots()
x = range(0,30)
ax3_4.semilogx(range(0,30),(y))
ax3_4.set_title('Validation Performance')
# ax3_4.set_xticks(np.arange(0,30, 1.0))
ax3_4.set_xlabel('i')
ax3_4.set_ylabel('Average Loss')
plt.show()
```

[image: Image here]

**UPDATE**: I understand you want to label the x-axis with values from 0..29, but on a log scale, all those numbers are very close.

Here is an image with xticks set (I din't get any errors):

```
fig3_4 ,ax3_4 = plt.subplots()
x = range(0,30)
ax3_4.semilogx(range(0,30),(y))
ax3_4.set_title('Validation Performance')
ax3_4.set_xticks(np.arange(0,30, 1.0))
ax3_4.set_xlabel('i')
ax3_4.set_ylabel('Average Loss')
plt.show()
```

[image: img]

Here is an image where I replace `semilogx` with `semilogy`.

```
fig3_4 ,ax3_4 = plt.subplots()
x = range(0,30)
ax3_4.semilogy(range(0,30),(y))
ax3_4.set_title('Validation Performance')
ax3_4.set_xticks(np.arange(0,30, 1.0))
ax3_4.set_xlabel('i')
ax3_4.set_ylabel('Average Loss')
plt.show()
```

[image]

Does any of this resemble your goal?

Comment: My issue is to set x-axis values to be 1,2,3,,,,,,29. That is why I mentioned that I tried to use ax3_4.set_xticks(np.arange(0,30, 1.0)). However, this line of code will throw me error if I use it's . By the way, sorry for the typo in my data, i tried to changed variable name to y, but not entirely. Thanks!

Comment: Ah, I see. Well, in a log scale, all the numbers from 1..29 will be very close to each other. I'll update the answer with some thoughts on the issue

Comment: I might add that I have made my plot in a Jupyter Notebook where I have already changed the plot style, so my colors and grids are probably different than yours. I use `plt.style.use('ggplot')`.